# How to track a selected process ALPC calls kernel-mode?

Tags: windows, kernel, rpc

I'm writing a driver that tracks a given PID's ALPC calls throughout the system.
The goal is to get a list of PID's to which the tracked PID communicated with during the session.

[zer0mem's blog - ALPC monitoring](http://www.zer0mem.sk/?p=542) was helpful but doesn't seem to achieve a real-time approach to the problem (i.e more of a snapshot).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.